# how to make append changes to an arraylist

Tags: java

I made this code, I am wondering what am I missing since when i return the list the new change i made to the position of j does not work!

```
static ArrayList<Integer> SmallChange(ArrayList<Integer> list, int j){
    int change = CS2004.UI(-5, 5); // this just makes a random int between -5 and 5.
    int newnum = change += list.get(j);
    if (newnum > list.size()){
        newnum = list.size();
    }
    else if (newnum < 0){
        newnum = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You need to put `newnum` back to the list. `list.set(j, newnum)`.

Comment: interesting so this re adds it to the list based on the position of j?

Comment: Yup. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)

Comment: Thanks, you've soled my question btw :)

Comment: You could just read the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) to find out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the old value of `j` with `newnum` by calling `list.set(j, newnum)` before you return the list at the end.

Even better, return a copy of the list instead of modifying the original list. Although in this case the modification to the list is trivial, it is is usually best to not modify parameters passed into a method. That is, keep your method without "side-effects" - instead of modifying the list passed in, you return a new list in this case.

Ex:

```
List<Integer> copiedList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
copiedList.set(j, newnum);
return copiedList;
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the list with the new number you would need to add the new calculated number back to the list at position J you can do this with the [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) command.

Your code should look something like the following

```
    static ArrayList<Integer> SmallChange(ArrayList<Integer> list, int j){
    int change = CS2004.UI(-5, 5); // this just makes a random int between -5 and 5.
    int newnum = change += list.get(j);
    if (newnum > list.size()){
        newnum = list.size();
    }
    else if (newnum < 0){
        newnum = 0;
    }
    list.set(j, newnum);
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
}
```

This will set index J to either 0, the list size, or the calculated value depending on which of your logic statements get executed